# SQL duration between dates for different persons

Tags: sql, duration

hopefully someone can help me with the following task:
I hVE got 2 tables Treatment  and 'Person'. `Treatment` contains the dates when treatments for the different persons were started, Person contains personal information, e.g. lastname.

Now I have to find all persons where the duration between the first and last treatment is over 20 years.
The Tables look something like this:

```
Person
| PK_Person | First name | Name |
_________________________________
| 1 | A_Test | Karl |
| 2 | B_Test | Marie |
| 3 | C_Test | Steve |
| 4 | D_Test | Jack |

Treatment
| PK_Treatment | Description | Starting time | PK_Person |
_________________________________________________________
| 1 | A | 01.01.1989 | 1
| 2 | B | 02.11.2001 | 1
| 3 | A | 05.01.2004 | 1
| 4 | C | 01.09.2013 | 1
| 5 | B | 01.01.1999 | 2
```

So in this example, the output should be person Karl, A_Test.

Hopefully its understandable what the problem is and someone can help me.

Edit: There seems to be a problem with the formatting, the tables are not displayed correctly, I hope its readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM person p
INNER JOIN Treatment t on t.PK_Person = p.PK_Person 
WHERE DATEDIFF(year,[TREATMENT_DATE_1], [TREATMENT_DATE_2]) > 20
```

This should do it, it is however untested so will need tweaking to your schema

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks a bit suspicious, because the first name doesn't look like a first name.

But, what you want to do is aggregate the `Treatment` table for each person and get the minimum and maximum starting times.  When the difference is greater than 20 years, then keep the person, and join back to the person table to get the names.

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName
from Person p join
     (select pk_person, MIN(StartingTime) as minst, MAX(StartingTime) as maxst
      from Treatment t
      group by pk_person
      having MAX(StartingTime) - MIN(StartingTime) > 20*365.25
     ) t
     on p.pk_person = t.pk_person;
```

Note that date arithmetic does vary between databases.  In most databases, taking the difference of two dates counts the number of days between them, so this is a pretty general approach (although not guaranteed to work on all databases).

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a slightly different approach and worked with SQL Fiddle to verify that the below statements work.

As mentioned previously, the data does seem a bit suspicious; nonetheless per your requirements, you would be able to do the following:

```
select P.PK_Person, p.FirstName, p.Name
from person P
  inner join treatment T on T.pk_person = P.pk_person
where DATEDIFF((select x.startingtime from treatment x where x.pk_person = p.pk_person order by startingtime desc limit 1), T.StartingTime) > 7305
```

First, we need to inner join treatements which will ignore any persons who are not in the treatment table.  The **where** portion now just needs to select based on your criteria (in this case a difference of dates).  Doing a subquery will generate the last date a person has been treated, compare that to each of your records, and filter by number of days (7305 = 20 years * 365.25).

[Here is the working SQL Fiddle sample.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff2e/10/0)